# Explaining a line of code in C - pointers and cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting, floating-point, integer

We have some float x and we convert it into  i, but could anyone please explain what does do in depth first &, then cast and finally *?

```
int i = *(int*)&x;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
&x
```

Gets a pointer to `x`

```
(int*)&x
```

Casts that pointer to an `int*`, i.e. a pointer to an `int`

```
*(int*)&x
```

Dereferences the resulting pointer, reading the memory of variable `x` as if it were an `int`.

Without knowing the type `x` is, it's hard to tell what the code's purpose. Most likely, if `x` is a `float`, it's being used to get the binary representation of the `float` (which is impossible to do by just casting to an `int`, because it does a float to int conversion)

Comment: It might be potentially dangerous if there are some alignment differiencies between `float` and `int` or say `sizeof(int) > sizeof(float)`. The only type that is safe for such nasty transformations is `void *` (but obviously such pointer cannot be dereferenced).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: `char*` is safe as well

Comment: note that unless `x` is already of type `int` or `unsigned int` (or points to a struct or union with an appropriate member of that type), this will violate the effective typing rules (aka strict aliasing)

Comment: How about: int i = (int)floor(x);  That will get the integer value by dropping/truncation of the fractional part.

Comment: @user3629249 That's much different from getting the binary representation of a float.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break it down

```
&x; //this gets you the address of x
(int *)&x; //this cast the address to be pointing at an integer value 
           //(before it was pointing at a float value)
*(int *)&x; // now the last * dereferences that value
```

assuming in your system, `long` is `8bytes` and `int` is `4bytes`. so you get only 4 bytes of the 8 bytes of x. As `int` is usually 4 bytes and `long` 8 bytes. Now which of the 4 bytes you get (the first 4 or the last 4) depends on the endianness of your system..

For more info on endianness, read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: This is assuming a 64 bit int value, which is a risky assumption.

Answer (score 0):

- `&x`: Get a pointer to x
- `(int*)`: Cast that pointer to a pointer to an int - this does not actually cast x
- `*`: Retrieve the value the pointer points to

Since a pointer cast doesn't actually perform type conversion, this line of code has the effect of reading the internal bits used to store the float `x`, and storing those bits int the integer `i`.  Basically, this is a reinterpret_cast.  (reinterpret_cast is a C++ feature, but it does exactly the same thing as this C syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

"&" means getting the reference of a variable. So &x gets the reference to a float and has type float*.

(int*) is a cast. Therefore you are casting from float* to int*.

The last "*" is for dereferencing the int*, that is, getting the value of the int*, which is an int.